# How to change labels in the projects page

Tags: wp-admin, support, post-type-support

​I want to change labels in this page ex: Client -> Owner
What is the file name where I can change these labels from?

screenshot:

https://snag.gy/75oUTb.jpg

I tried to do it by javascript, but it caused effect on all website pages, on previewing, editing or updating, the page turns to white.

This is my piece of code

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            window.onload = replaceTxt; 
             function replaceTxt() {
             var vr1 = document.getElementById('_bunch_bunch_projects_settings[client]').childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML;

             var vr11 = vr1.replace('Client','Owner');
}
             </script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

"Projects" are a common Custom Post Type. How is yours generated? However it is done, if it is done properly, the labels will have language strings that can be translated for localization/internationalization with any number of plugins that offer this functionality.

Comment: I don't know actually how it is generated. It's not a plugin anyways.

Comment: Check your theme `functions.php` file. That's probably where the CPT (and maybe a custom taxonomy for it) is being created if not a plugin.